# How to upgrade Log4j1.x version to Log4j2.x Version

Tags: activemq-classic

Currently our application using Log4j1.version.There is an requirement to Upgrade Log4j1.x to Log2.x version.

Actions we performed are below.

1.We deployed Log4j-core-2.17.1 and Log4j-2.17.1-api and we upgraded log4j.properties file to log4j2.version but activemq service is failed to start.

Can anyone Please guide us on this.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who run into this same issue in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Log4j 2.x with ActiveMQ then you need to [upgrade ActiveMQ to version 5.17.0](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/). Only version 5.17.0 has the internal changes necessary to be able to use Log4j 2.x. Those changes were made via [AMQ-7426](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-7426).